# Joining a single row to a query

Tags: mysql

I need to get a value from another table but where there may be 5/6 results, I only need to show the latest one. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT s.Mileage
     , s.PurchasePrice
     , v.make
     , v.model
     , v.vrm
     , c.CleanLive 
  FROM StockBook s
  LEFT 
  JOIN Vehicles v
    ON v.VehicleID = s.VehicleID
  LEFT 
  JOIN CapVals c
    ON c.LeadID = (SELECT C1.CleanLive 
                   FROM CapVals C1
                  WHERE s.LeadID = c.LeadID
                  ORDER 
                     BY C1.Date 
                  LIMIT 1
                ) 
 ORDER 
    BY StockBookID
```

Which is working as a query but not showing CleanLive value.

I've set up a sample data set and DB Fiddle here:

```
CREATE TABLE `Vehicles` (
  `VehicleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vrm` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `StockBook` (
  `StockBookID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LeadID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mileage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PurchasePrice` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `CapVals` (
  `CapValsID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LeadID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CleanLive` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Vehicles` (`VehicleID`, `vrm`, `make`, `model`) VALUES
(1, 'M900WRD', 'Vauxhall', 'Signum');

INSERT INTO `StockBook` (`StockBookID`, `LeadID`, `VehicleID`, `Mileage`, `PurchasePrice`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 17000, 15000.00);

INSERT INTO `CapVals` (`CapValsID`, `LeadID`, `CleanLive`, `Date`) VALUES
(6455, 1, 1540, '2019-12-04 15:02:29'),
(6456, 1, 1540, '2019-12-04 15:02:29'),
(6457, 1, 1540, '2019-12-04 15:02:29');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4fQuMVpXHGxqgYJ4ia92w/4

Comment: There is only one row in each table, so the whole limit thing seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT Stock.Mileage, Stock.PurchasePrice, Vehi.make, Vehi.model, Vehi.vrm,
(SELECT CleanLive from CapVals a WHERE a.LeadID = Stock.LeadID ORDER BY  DATE DESC LIMIT 1) AS CleanLive
FROM StockBook Stock
LEFT JOIN Vehicles Vehi
ON Stock.VehicleID=Vehi.VehicleID
ORDER BY StockBookID
```

Comment: The edited version works a charm. Many thanks @Thushan

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v.vehicleID 
     , v.vrm     
     , v.make     
     , v.model  
     , s.stockbookid
     , s.leadid
     , s.mileage 
     , s.purchaseprice 
     , c.capvalsid
     , c.cleanlive 
     , c.date               
  FROM vehicles v 
  JOIN stockbook s 
    ON s.vehicleid = v.vehicleid 
  JOIN capvals c 
    ON c.leadid = s.leadid
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT leadid,MAX(capvalsid) capvalsid FROM capvals GROUP BY leadid ) x
    ON x.leadid = c.leadid 
   AND x.capvalsid = c.capvalsid;
+-----------+---------+----------+--------+-------------+--------+---------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| vehicleID | vrm     | make     | model  | stockbookid | leadid | mileage | purchaseprice | capvalsid | cleanlive | date                |
+-----------+---------+----------+--------+-------------+--------+---------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 | M900WRD | Vauxhall | Signum |           1 |      1 |   17000 |      15000.00 |      6457 |      1540 | 2019-12-04 15:02:29 |
+-----------+---------+----------+--------+-------------+--------+---------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Row_number concept, which will avoid the duplicate rows and give you recent one,

<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4fQuMVpXHGxqgYJ4ia92w/8)</kbd>

```
SELECT Stock.Mileage, Stock.PurchasePrice, Vehi.make, Vehi.model, Vehi.vrm,
            X.CleanLive as CleanLive
FROM StockBook Stock
LEFT JOIN Vehicles Vehi ON Stock.VehicleID=Vehi.VehicleID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT @LeadID:=LeadID,C1.LeadID, CleanLive, C1.Date, @row_number:=CASE WHEN @LeadID = LeadID THEN               @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS num
FROM CapVals AS C1, (SELECT @LeadID:=0,@row_number:=0) as t ORDER BY  C1.Date DESC) X ON X.LeadID = Stock.LeadID AND X.num = 1
ORDER BY StockBookID
```